# ZF2 - How to correctly concatenate a select statement containing a CONCAT function

Tags: postgresql, zend-framework

I'm new to Zend and to Postgres. My `Users` table contains a `FirstName` column and a `LastName` column.

I want to query the table using a single 'full name' string; e.g. `$search = 'John Sm'`.

I'm trying to use the `CONCAT_WS` function to concatenate the two names from the table, and then compare this with the search string.

**My statement**

`$select->where(array('CONCAT_WS(" ", "u"."FirstName", "u"."LastName") LIKE ?' => array("%$search%")));`

I've tried different combinations but can't seem to get the concatenation right.

An example of the statement I want is `SELECT * FROM Users WHERE 'firstname lastname' LIKE '%john s%'`

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question, but have you considered making a view for this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the latest version of the documentation?

https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.statement.html

Answer (score 0):

If you use array as parameter in your `$select->where()` it is interpreted as pairs `['column1' => 'value', 'column2' => 'value']`. In this solution you can't use functions and combined parts of query.

You can use `Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Literal()`, eg.:

```
$select->where
  ->literal('CONCAT_WS(" ", "u"."FirstName", "u"."LastName") LIKE \'%word%\'')
```

or use `Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Expression()`, eg.:

```
$select->where
      ->expression('CONCAT_WS(" ", "u"."FirstName", "u"."LastName") LIKE \'%?%\'', $word)
```

(second parameter can bee array if variables is more)

In this solution you can build sql `WHERE` using the same method

```
$select->where
  ->equalsTo()
  ->or
  ->greatherThan()
  ->and
  ->like()
  ->nest()
    ->lessThan()
    ->or
    ->literal()
  ->unnest()
  ...
```

https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.db.sql.html#id7

Also you can build as `Zend\Db\Sql\Where`  /   `Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate` as eg.:

```
$where = new Where();
$where->equalsTo();// and more, more, more, with sub-where inclusive
$select->where->predicate($where);
```